# Adding view on top of android.R.id.content with alignment

Tags: android, layout, alignment, parameters

Making a small library that extends a webview.

I have a method such that:

```
public static MyView create(final Activity a, final int type, final int location, final View v)
```

On a MyView, you call a .show() which just makes it visible, this it returns this.

So in an activity, you do this:

```
MyView.create(this, 0, 0, this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

In the create, I want to add to the view given (v) and display on top of everything the new view.  I can create the view fine.  However, I can't position it correctly.

I've tried to follow other peoples steps, creating a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and assigning it a rule that's ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, but the view won't go to the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what does the title mean?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it.  Had two ideas going at once lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try hosting the WebView and your custom view inside a FrameLayout, with the WebView as the background frame.

Comment: Tried to do this earlier, but it didn't work correctly.  But I found a way to make it work, thanks for bringing it up again.